# Lambda expression for operator overloading

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is it possible to write lambda expression for overloading operators?

For example, I have the following structure:

```
struct X{
    int value;
    //(I can't modify this structure)
};
```

`X` needs `==` operator

```
int main()
{
    X a = { 123 };
    X b = { 123 };
    //[define equality operator for X inside main function]
    //if(a == b) {}
    return 0;
}
```

`==` operator can be defined as `bool operator==(const X& lhs, const X& rhs){...}`, but this requires adding a separate function, and my comparison is valid only within a specific function.

`auto compare = [](const X& lhs, const X& rhs){...}` will solve the problem. I was wondering if I can write this lambda as an operator.

Comment: I don't understand the problem in using a non-member operator function. Can you elaborate?

Comment: A lambda is an object. An object cannot have a name like `operator==`. Only a function can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to write lambda expression for overloading operators?

No.

Operator overload functions must be functions or function templates. They can be member functions, member function templates, non-member functions, or non-member function templates. However, they cannot be lambda expressions.

From the [C++11 Standard/13.5 Overloaded operators, para 6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over.oper#6):

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration.

Comment: Not all operators can be non-member functions, e.g. `operator=`.

Comment: @HenriMenke, True. That is an additional constraint.