# Parameterized operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Let us assume we have a type `X`, whose values we want to compare. Assume further that there is not just one comparison but a family of comparisons, parameterized by a value of another type `T`. In other words, let's assume we are given a function of the prototype:

```
bool f(T p, X v1, X v2);
```

Given a parameter `p`, `f(p, v1, v2)` shall be true if `v1` compares less than `v2` under the order corresponding to `p`.

What I am looking for, now, is a way to overload the `<` operator in a lexical scope given a value `p` of type `T` such that `v1 < v2` is compiled into `f(p, v1, v2)` locally in that scope.

Just for illustration, the following does achieve what I want in Scheme, where `...` denotes the lexical scope in question:

```lisp
(let ((< (lambda (v1 v2) (f p v1 v2))))
  ...)
```

I have two ideas on how to get almost what I want in C++, but I'm not satisfied with them.

The first idea is not to define the comparison operator between values of type `X` but between values of type `std::pair <T, X>`. Instead of `v1 < v2` one would have to write `std::pair (p, v1) < std::pair (p, v2)` and `std::pair (p1, v2) < std::pair (p2, v2)` is overloaded to compile to `f(p1, v1, v2)`. The problem with this approach is, for example, that the second parameter `p2` is completely superfluous. Leaving it out destroys the symmetry.

My second idea is to use something like expression templates. Here, `v1 < v2` does not return a boolean but just an abstract expression (tree) that is evaluated like this `p (v1 < v2)`, where `p ()` is suitably overloaded. The problem with this approach is that one cannot overload `bool (v1 < v2)`, in particular, expressions like `v1 < v2 ? ... : ...` won't compile.

Comment: Why the aversion to using the predicate function directly? That's much more likely to be optimized away by the compiler and is easier to read when the types provided already have an `operator<` overload.

Comment: The relevant type `X` for my use case does not have an `operator<` overload. The reason why I would like to use `operator<` is the naturality of the notation. My use case is a mathematical library where the user shall be able to use the usual mathematical notation as much as possible. Think of the type `X` as the type of monomials (in some fixed finite set of indeterminates), for example, and of the type `T` as the type of monomial orderings.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really following this question. It seems to be constructed in an unnecessarily complex and academic manner. Can you _simply_ explain what you want to do, what you've tried so far, and what bits you're stuck on? Use examples, in [mcve] form. At the moment my knee-jerk suggestion is _just overload `operator<`_ but you seem to have rejected that idea from the off.

Comment: "v1 < v2 is compiled into f(p, v1, v2)". It is not possible to ensure that. In C++ operator are functions. So all possible solutions will involve either the generation of a bunch of functions that will pollute the executable file, or end-up in using a static variable, and you will get an evaluation penalty, trouble with multi-threading, etc. I would keep the `f(p,v1,v2)` notation or I would create a new notation: `v1 <p< v2`, `p1 << v1 < v2`, etc...

Comment: @Oliv Except this can (and should) be trivially inlined. What does multi-threading have to do with it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In simple terms, I am asking how close I can get with C++'s operator overloading to the piece of Scheme code I wrote above. If you want a concrete example, please take a look at my example comparing monomials where the order is parameterized by a chosen monomial ordering and where I would like to use the mathematical notation.

Comment: @Oliv The basic problem seems to be that the C++ operator functions cannot be closures (like the one in my Scheme code above). Using a static variable can be made thread-safe by making it a thread-local one. But this will most likely hamper the performance. Also, it will change the meaning of `<` depending on the parameter in a dynamic scope and not in a lexical scope.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
#include <iostream>

struct PointA {
    int x, y;
    static bool(*compareLarger)(PointA const&, PointA const&);
    bool
    operator >(PointA const& rhs) const {
        return compareLarger(*this, rhs);
    }
};

bool(*PointA::compareLarger)(PointA const&, PointA const&) = nullptr;

bool
compareX(PointA const& lhs, PointA const& rhs) {
    return lhs.x > rhs.x;
}

bool
compareY(PointA const& lhs, PointA const& rhs) {
    return lhs.y > rhs.y;
}

int
main(int, char**) {
    PointA p1{0, 1}, p2{1, 0};
    PointA::compareLarger = compareX;
    if (p1 > p2) std::cout << "P1 is larger\n";
    else std::cout << "P2 is larger\n";
    PointA::compareLarger = compareY;
    if (p1 > p2) std::cout << "P1 is larger\n";
    else std::cout << "P2 is larger\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Is that what you're thinking of?

EDIT:

This would even resolve it t compile time, if that's important:

```
#include <iostream>

struct PointA {
    int x, y;
};

namespace NS1 {
    bool
    operator>(PointA const& lhs, PointA const& rhs) {
        return lhs.x > rhs.x;
    }
}

namespace NS2 {
    bool
    operator>(PointA const& lhs, PointA const& rhs) {
        return lhs.y > rhs.y;
    }
}

int
main(int, char**) {
    PointA p1{0, 1}, p2{1, 0};
    {
        using NS1::operator >;
        if (p1 > p2) std::cout << "P1 is larger\n";
        else std::cout << "P2 is larger\n";
    }
    {
        using NS2::operator >;
        if (p1 > p2) std::cout << "P1 is larger\n";
        else std::cout << "P2 is larger\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. To make your first solution thread-safe, `PointA::compareLarger` should be a thread-local variable, which may hamper the performance. Otherwise, it is almost a solution: It changes `operator>` dynamically and not in lexical scope.

In your second example, the parameterization of `operator>` happens in a lexical scope, which is exactly what my question is about. However, the second example has a different problem: The choice of `operator>` depends on a compile-time value (`NS1` vs `NS2`). I need dependence on a run-time value (of type `T` in my question).

Comment: I see. I don't think it's possible what you want then in C++. You would need a lambda to overload an operator, something like (hypothetically) `auto operator> = [](PointA& lhs, PointB& rhs) {return lhs.x > rhs.y;};`. Such a construct doesn't exist in C++ to my knowledge. It also says it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994213/lambda-expression-for-operator-overloading

Answer (score 1):

I don't really agree with your use case, but it's an interesting question nonetheless. My favorite thing about C++ is how it gives you so much control - so much in fact that most other languages' features can be simulated via clever C++. This case is no exception.

Here's a solution I just thew together that should be quite similar to scheme. It changes the comparator used for specific types and in specific threads for the duration of the declaring scope. I've included comments to explain all the important bits.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

struct vector2
{
    int x, y;

    // the type of comparator to use (function pointer)
    typedef bool(*comparator_t)(const vector2&, const vector2&);
    // gets the value of comparator we're currently using by reference (one for each thread)
    static comparator_t &comparator()
    {
        thread_local comparator_t c = nullptr;
        return c;
    }

    // define comparison operator to use comparator()
    friend bool operator<(const vector2 &a, const vector2 &b) { return comparator()(a, b); }
};

// a sentry type for changing the comparator for type T in the current scope
// it changes it back upon destruction (at end of scope)
template<typename T>
struct comparator_sentry_t
{
    typename T::comparator_t old;
    explicit comparator_sentry_t(typename T::comparator_t c) : old(std::exchange(T::comparator(), c)) {}
    ~comparator_sentry_t() { T::comparator() = old; }
};

#define _MERGE(x, y) x ## y
#define MERGE(x, y) _MERGE(x, y)

// a user-level macro which is used to change the comparator for the rest of the current scope
#define SET_COMPARATOR(type, cmp) comparator_sentry_t<type> MERGE(__comparator_sentry, __LINE__) { (cmp) }

// -- below this line is demo code -- //

// a couple of example comparison functions
bool cmp_x_less(const vector2 &a, const vector2 &b) { return a.x < b.x; }
bool cmp_x_greater(const vector2 &a, const vector2 &b) { return a.x > b.x; }

bool cmp_y_less(const vector2 &a, const vector2 &b) { return a.y < b.y; }
bool cmp_y_greater(const vector2 &a, const vector2 &b) { return a.y > b.y; }

// some functions to demonstrate this works across function invocations
void foo(const vector2 &a, const vector2 &b)
{
    assert(a < b);
    SET_COMPARATOR(vector2, cmp_y_greater);
}
void bar(const vector2 &a, const vector2 &b)
{
    assert(b < a);
    SET_COMPARATOR(vector2, cmp_x_less);
}

int main()
{
    vector2 a{ 1, 3 };
    vector2 b{ 2, 6 };

    SET_COMPARATOR(vector2, cmp_x_less);
    SET_COMPARATOR(vector2, cmp_x_less); // redeclaring in same scope is ok

    assert(a < b);
    foo(a, b);     // changes comparator internally
    assert(a < b); // demonstrate that said change is reverted at end of function

    {
        // change comparator for this scope
        SET_COMPARATOR(vector2, cmp_y_greater);

        assert(b < a);
        bar(a, b);
        assert(b < a);
    }

    assert(a < b); // demonstrate the comparator change was reverted
    foo(a, b);
    assert(a < b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a very clever code. I like the automatic resetting through the use of destructors. Unfortunately, it still does not solve the original problem; the reparametrization of the `<` operator happens in a dynamic and not in lexical scope. (In your example, `bar` sees the change made in the main function.)

Comment: The Scheme code corresping to your solution would be: `(define current-< (make-parameter #f)) (define (< x y) ((current-<) x y)) (parameterize ((current-< (lambda (x y) (f p x y))) ...)`

Comment: @Marc I see... What should the default behavior for `operator<` be? If there is none, shouldn't it be defined in each function before use? This solution would handle that.

Comment: If the parameter of `operator<` is not set in the lexical scope, it should result in a compilation error at best if it is used there.

Comment: @Marc I still say the best way is to use this solution and simply declare which comparator you want at the start of each function. Unfortunately generating a compile error is impossible, but you could take an extra param in each function (defaulted to `{}`) which would reset the comparator to `nullptr` via its constructor, then make `operator<` throw an exception if it's currently null upon use.